# Why Inertias are represented as parallelepiped in GAZEBO 2.1.0

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

As title, what is the meaning of that parallelepipeds? Should not they be allipsoid?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5016/why-inertias-are-represented-as-parallelepiped-in-gazebo-2.1.0/) by [Enrico Mingo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/507/enrico-mingo/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 121 on 2013-11-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The inertia visualization in Gazebo 2.1 shows the dimensions of a box of uniform density with equivalent mass and moment of inertia values (though off-axis terms are not yet considered). It could also be shown as an ellipsoid; we implemented the visualization as a box, since it was simpler.

For reference:

[gazebo pull request 745](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-request/745/visualize-moment-of-inertia-fix-203/diff), when the feature was implemented.

[gazebo issue 203](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/203/offer-moi-and-com-visualization), which was the feature request for inertia visualization.

[gazebo issue 880](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/880/moi-visualization-doesnt-consider-off), which is an outstanding issue to consider off-diagonal terms in the inertia matrix during visualization.

We should add some of this information to the wiki. Thanks for asking.

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2013-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0